# Example of Erdos-Szekeres bound being tight

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I know that Erdos-Szekeres Theorem states that any sequence of $k^2+1$ real numbers contains a monotonic subsequence of length at least $k+1$.  I know that it is a least upper bound since there exist sequences of $k^2$ real numbers that do not contain a monotonic subsequence of length $k+1$.

First, I was asked to prove the Erdos-Szekeres Theorem in two different ways, which was done accordingly. Then, I was asked to  Describe an example which shows that the bound given by the Erd}os-SzekeresTheorem is tight.

I have little clue on how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $k=4$:

```
                                               *  
                                                 *  
                                                   *  
                                                     *  
                                      *  
                                        *  
                                          *  
                                            *  
                             *  
                               *  
                                 *  
                                   *  
                    *  
                      *  
                        *  
                          *
```

Comment: do you mean that by putting $k=4$ we get a sequence of $17$ real numbers and the monotonic subsequence should have length $5$. Should I connect the stars and show that each path that exists has at least 5 positive-slopes edges? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @curious_math: No. The picture, properly interpreted, is an example of a sequence of $16$ real numbers that does not have a monotone subsequence of length $5$.

Comment: Got it. we show that there exist sequences of $k^2$ real numbers that do not contain a monotonic subsequence of length $k+1$. Thank you so much!

Comment: @curious_math: You’re welcome!